# FileSystemWatcher not firing events for files opened in ffmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm trying to check the last time a file has changed its size using FileSystemWatcher but the file is still opened in another program(ffmpeg.exe). I don't know why the changed event is not fired.
Following is my code:

```
using (var proc = new Process())
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Iniciando gravação da stream:"+url);
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\ffmpeg.exe";
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-y -i " + url + @" -ab 32k -ac 1 -ar 11025 " + idStation + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".mp3";

                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                proc.Start();

                proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
                proc.BeginErrorReadLine();


                proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(CheckOutput);

                FileSystemWatcher fileSizeChecker = new FileSystemWatcher();
                fileSizeChecker.Changed += WatchFile;
                fileSizeChecker.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + idStation + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".mp3");
                fileSizeChecker.Filter = Path.GetFileName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + idStation + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".mp3");
                fileSizeChecker.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                fileSizeChecker.BeginInit();
            }
static void WatchFile(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("T") + "] Watcher changed!");
    }
```

WatchFile is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of FileSystemWatcher in this circumstance is discussed here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf042bd2-2219-4fb7-ac12-57e79d389a09/filesystemwatcher-question-when-file-is-already-open-for-writing-size-event-does-not-fire?forum=csharplanguage

The file size change event does not fire until the file is closed.